# Finding spread of values between multiple arrays of different shapes in a line graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, linegraph, spread

I am plotting 16 arrays with different shapes onto one plot.However, things are getting difficult because what I would like to do is plot the maximum spread of data by essentially finding the maximum and minimum value at each point on the y-axis and shading between this area.

It would hopefully look something like this, except my lines are vertical so the spread would be across on the x rather than the y as shown here.

[image]

For simplicity, I'm working with some very simplified dummy data to figure out the best way to do this, but ultimately I'll be plotting more data with much larger lengths and a bit different values.

```
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np 

d1 = np.random.randint(0,10,15)
d2 = np.random.randint(0,10,20)
d3 = np.random.randint(0,10,25)
d4 = np.random.randint(0,10,30)

y1=np.linspace(0,30,15,True)
y2=np.linspace(0,30,20,True)
y3=np.linspace(0,30,25,True)
y4=np.linspace(0,30,30,True)

plt.style.use('bmh')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,15))

plt.plot(d1,y1,'red')
plt.plot(d2,y2,'blue')
plt.plot(d3,y3,'green')
plt.plot(d4,y4,'orange')

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,11,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,31,1))

plt.show()
```

And with this code, this is currently what the plot looks like as shown on the left. What I want is something like on the right (which I did quickly by hand as an example) with the area between the black lines shaded. As you can see below, the black line follows whatever line is farthest on the outside (i.e. the smallest and largest values at each y point), and then I'd like to shade this region in between the two black lines.

[image][image]

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: I see that you also consider the intersection of two straight lines as a point on the black line. Since you have same `x` axis but different `y` axis, you would definitely need some continuous curve or some sort of interpolation on a fine mesh with same number of `y` values so that you can use some loop or in built function to get the `min` and `max` at each `y` value. Having this, it's straightforward to fill the space between them.

Comment: I haven't done much interpolation and the little I have done was with `cdo remapbil`. Is there a similar straightforward function that I could use to interpolate? I think I should be able to get the shading in between just fine, it's the line plotting part I'm having trouble figuring out.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have on the top of my mind a solution to interpolate these random lines. But wait for others' solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you anyway! Hopefully I can find something that works.

Comment: Here's the steps for a numeric solution: you interpolate the four lines (d1, ... d4) on a common grid such as `y_common = np.linspace(0, 30, 150)`. That gives you the 4 lines again but sampled with more points. Now you can stack the four lines with `np.vstack` and use `np.min` and `np.max` on the stacked array. That won't give you the intersections exactly but it will get you as close as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the advice people gave! I think I figured things out and I'll show how I did it. The graphs are a little different because I reran the entire code and of course I got a new set of random numbers for each of the dummy datasets.

I ultimately needed to interpolate the data to make them all the same length and from there I was able to stack them, find the max and min at each y, and then plot. You'll see the interpolation doesn't give a perfect representation, but I'm assuming that's in part because these are pretty small datasets with a larger step between values and for larger ones with a smaller step between values, it will do a little better.

```
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp

d1 = np.random.randint(0,10,15)
d2 = np.random.randint(0,10,20)
d3 = np.random.randint(0,10,25)
d4 = np.random.randint(0,10,30)

y1=np.linspace(0,30,15)
y2=np.linspace(0,30,20)
y3=np.linspace(0,30,25)
y4=np.linspace(0,30,30)

y_common = np.linspace(0,30,30)

x1 = np.interp(y_common,y1,d1)
x2 = np.interp(y_common,y2,d2)
x3 = np.interp(y_common,y3,d3)
x4 = np.interp(y_common,y4,d4)

x = np.stack((x1,x2,x3,x4))

xmax = np.max(x,axis=0)
xmin = np.min(x,axis=0)

%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('bmh')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,15))

plt.plot(d1,y1,'red')
plt.plot(d2,y2,'blue')
plt.plot(d3,y3,'green')
plt.plot(d4,y4,'orange')

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,11,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,31,1))

plt.show()



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,15))

plt.plot(x1,y_common,'#A2A2A2')
plt.plot(x2,y_common,'#A2A2A2')
plt.plot(x3,y_common,'#A2A2A2')
plt.plot(x4,y_common,'#A2A2A2')

plt.plot(xmax,y_common,'black')
plt.plot(xmin,y_common,'black')

plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'black'
plt.fill_betweenx(y_common, xmax, xmin, facecolor='none', hatch ='/', edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,11,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,31,1))

plt.show()
```

Here are the resulting plots with the original before interpolation on the left and the plot with interpolation and a few other changes to match what I want my final graph to look like with my own data.

[image][image]